# Eigen - Sparse matrix solvers surprisingly slow for simple case

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

I'm trying to solve a linear system for a finite element case:

`d = F/K`

Where `K` is a sparse matrix 25,000x25,000 and 360,000 non-zero values which is only 0.05% of the entire matrix. And `F` is a 25,000x1 matrix filled with mostly zeros.

Solving this system is taking a surprising amount of time:

```
Sparse Solver        Compute + Solve Time
ConjugateGradient    70.2s
BiCGSTAB             40.2s
SimplicialLDLT       40.1s
SimplicialCholesky   32.9s
SimplicialLLT        29.0s
```

Where the solvers are used in a standard way e.g.

```
VectorXd F_vector(25000);
// fill F_vector
VectorXd d_vector(25000);
BiCGSTAB<SparseMatrix<double> > solver;
solver.compute(K_sparse);
d_vector = solver.solve(F_vector);
```

(Also, a 10% increase to the size of the dimensions resulted in a 10%^2 increase in the time. I'm not sure if that's noteworthy but I'll state it in case it's not)

Is there something wrong with my implementation or understanding of these sparse solvers?

Comment: (1) Use a sparse vector instead of dense, there are [separate `solve` functions](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SparseSolverBase.html) for these cases, I guess the sparse one is faster. (2) Make sure you compile with `-DNDEBUG`.

Comment: @HenriMenke, using a sparse vecteur for the right hand side won't help, but yes make sure you enabled compiler optimizations, like `-O3` with gcc/clang.

Comment: @HenriMenke Oh I didn't know about this, that cut the fastest time down from 30s to 6s, thanks for that. Any other flags I should be aware of?

Comment: @ggael Trying all of `-O2`, `-O3`, `-Ofast` didn't show anything meaningful. They were all roughly the same speed. If anything, the faster flags seemed to slow down execution times. Anything else I might be missing?